# Find the number of $2$-Sylow of $D_{10}$

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, dihedral-groups

Find the number of $2$-Sylow of $D_{10}$

I got this problem of group theory. I tried to solve it this way:

Using third Sylow theorem, we know that the number of $5$-Sylow is $1$, so we have only one subgroup $H$ of order $5$ of $G=D_{10}$, with $|G|=20$. Also, we have that the number of $2$-Sylow is either $1$ or $5$, so if $n_2=1$, we have only one subgroup $K$ of order $4$, and we know that both $H$ and $K$ are normal in $G$, so $G$ is isomorphic with the external direct product of its Sylow normal subgroups, so it's either $\Bbb Z_4\times\Bbb Z_5$ or $\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_5$, but in both cases $G$ would be abelian, so a contradiction.

Is it right?

Thank you for all of your support.

Comment: Note that there are two conventions for notation in the dihedral group: the index can refer to the number of elements, or to the object whose rigid motions comprise the group. So while $D_5$ would be unambiguous (refering to the group of rigid motions of a regular pentagon, having 10 elements), the notation $D_{10}$ is ambiguous: it could either be the dihedral group with ten elements, or the dihedral group with 20 elements (the convention you seem to follow); it is best to always specify which convention you are using when the index is even.

Comment: Thank you all!!